# How do I disable physics for multiple objects at once?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I'm using multiple rigid body spheres to fill a mesh after I converted them from particles to mesh. Now after a few frames of them jumping around and reaching equilibrium(almost), I want to freeze them relative to the mesh since the mesh will need to move afterwards. I am not able to use the "**copy from active**" when the active object doesn't have any physics enabled. I can only copy physics of an object and paste it to the one without any physics but not the other way around. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found out the (obvious)solution. Select all the objects with physics - go to object[top left]> Rigid body> Remove.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to OP's answer, you can also click *Apply Transformation* before removing the Rigid Body to freeze any Rigid Body Sim you want in place.

For example I used it to stick a stack of children's clocks in place.